# typescript - create a callback function

Tags: javascript, web, typescript

hey guys i'd like to know how to make a callback function in typescript.

I know how to do it in vanilla JS :

```
function mySandwich(param1, param2, callback) {
alert('Started eating my sandwich.\n\nIt has: ' + param1 + ', ' + param2);
callback();}

mySandwich('ham', 'cheese', function() {
alert('Finished eating my sandwich.');});
```

But i can't find a way to do it with TS.
you guys have an example of it?

thank you!

Comment: I'll do it in exactly the same way (btw, ES5 is subset of TypeScript so everything you write in ES5 is a valid TypeScript as well).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Typescript is a superset of javascript, so any javascript code is valid typescript code.

But you can use types for safety:

```
function mySandwich(param1: string, param2: string, callback: () => void) {
    alert('Started eating my sandwich.\n\nIt has: ' + param1 + ', ' + param2);
    callback();
}

mySandwich('ham', 'cheese', function() {
    alert('Finished eating my sandwich.');
});

mySandwich('ham'); // Error: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

mySandwich('ham', 'cheese', (num: number) => 4 * num); // Error: Argument of type '(num: number) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => void'
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20mySandwich(param1%3A%20string%2C%20param2%3A%20string%2C%20callback%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20alert('Started%20eating%20my%20sandwich.%5Cn%5CnIt%20has%3A%20'%20%2B%20param1%20%2B%20'%2C%20'%20%2B%20param2)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20callback()%3B%0A%7D%0A%0AmySandwich('ham'%2C%20'cheese'%2C%20function()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20alert('Finished%20eating%20my%20sandwich.')%3B%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0AmySandwich('ham')%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%3A%20Supplied%20parameters%20do%20not%20match%20any%20signature%20of%20call%20target%0A%0AmySandwich('ham'%2C%20'cheese'%2C%20(num%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%204%20*%20num)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%3A%20Argument%20of%20type%20'(num%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20number'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20parameter%20of%20type%20'()%20%3D%3E%20void'))